# Oracle - Can't login after creating user

Tags: oracle

I can't login after creating user, here is my code

```
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = XEPDB1;
CREATE USER hello IDENTIFIED BY a;
GRANT CONNECT TO hello;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO hello;

CONN hello/a;
```

Script ouput

```
Session altered.


User HELLO created.


Grant succeeded.


Grant succeeded.

Error starting at line : 26 in command -
  connect ...
Error report -
Connection Failed
  USER          = hello
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XEPDB1
  Error Message = ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
Commit
```

I have tried

```
CONN hello/a@XEPDB1;
```

Output

```
SQL> conn hello/a@xepdb1
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
```

How can I fix this? I have already added a listener_xepdb1 in tnsnames.ora and set it on with this but still couldn't fix it

```
SQL> alter system set local_listener='LISTENER_XEPDB1';
```

Comment: Please post your code directly in your question; not links to images.

Comment: In order to use the `@xepdb1` you have to add an entry in your tnsnames.ora

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should have used

```
conn hello/a@xepdb1
            -------
            you're missing this
```

Comment: I tried this, it gives me this error
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: Does your TNSNAMES.ORA file contain an alias named xepdb1? If not, that might be the reason of ORA-12154.

Comment: try this `sqlplus hello/a@localhost:1521/xepdb1` or add service entry in `tnsnames.ora` file